# Lock computer on ubuntu but with screen still visible

Tags: ubuntu

How do you make Ubuntu lock the computer but leave what's on the screen visible? I don't care if people see what's on my screen, in fact, it's my work, so I want people to see it, but I don't want them to be able to use the keyboard or mouse until I unlock it with my password.

So how do you lock Ubuntu without the black overlay?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be able to use [`xtrlock`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/xtrlock.1x.html).

From the `man` page:

> xtrlock locks the X server till the user enters their password  at  the
>          keyboard.
>
> While  xtrlock  is  running, the mouse and keyboard are grabbed and the
>          mouse cursor becomes a padlock.  Output displayed by  X  programs,  and
>          windows  put  up  by new X clients, continue to be visible, and any new
>          output is displayed normally.

[Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xtrlock)
[Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xtrlock)